# NullPointer exception and FileInputStream

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, fileinputstream

I have a NPE when I execute the line `FileInputStream ifs=openFileInput(fileName);` I get a NPE. I get the same NPE when I execute

`FileInputStream ifs=getApplicationContext().openFileInput(fileName);`

The full stacktrace is here.

```
07-25 22:00:35.852  25063-25063/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
at com.ollien.flashcarder.MainActivity.setPagerFile(MainActivity.java:353)
at com.ollien.flashcarder.SetsFragment$1.onItemClick(SetsFragment.java:47)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1215)
at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:4506)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2959)
at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could someone help? I don't quite know why this is happening. fileName is not null, and is equal to `"hi there.txt"`Thanks!

Comment: Can you check to see if getApplicationContext() returns null? Just with a log. If you are sure filename isn't null

Comment: Are you ever calling `attachBaseContext()` in `onItemClick` or `setPagerFile` by chance?  I ask because both `getApplicationContext()` and `openFileInput()` have a call to mBaseContext.SOMETHING, so if you're setting that to null then that would explain the NPE.

Comment: @Nicholas getApplicationContext(); throws a NPE when I try to System.out it

Comment: @Jonathan No, I've actually never heard of attachBaseContext(). What should I be doing for that?

Comment: No, probably not.  However, a call to `openFileInput()` is literally only a call to `mBase.openFileInput()`, and `getApplicationContext()` is similar.  The only way that could be the top of your null pointer stack would be if `mBase` is null.  Can you post the code to `setPagerFile()`?

Comment: setPagerFile() is actually just that FileInputStream in a function. I actually found the solution though based on your question. I passed in the context to the setPagerFile() and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Obviously FileInputStream has nothing to do with it. It doesn't appear in the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
Make sure that your Context is not null, I passed it in via function arguments, for example
`public void setPagerFile(String fileName,Context mContext){`
then use mContext as your context.